# Single value extraction from ResultSelector in AWS Step Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I'm struggling with something that seems like it should be simple, but the 'obvious' approach isn't working :-|. I have an AWS Step Function Lambda step. The input to that step (and function) looks like so:

```
{ "foo":"aaa" , "bar":"bbb" }
```

The Lambda's output looks like so:

```
{
  // a bunch of Lambda execution details here
  "Payload" : { "baz":"ccc" , "qux":"ddd" }
}
```

I'd like for the step's output to be:

```
{ "foo":"aaa" , "bar":"bbb" , "fred":"ccc" }
```

... i.e. I want to overlay the step's input with a new value at key "fred" referencing the Lambda output's value at "baz".

My first attempt (which still seems the most logical) is to 'extract' only "ccc" from the Lambda output and inject it into the step's output, like so:

```
"ResultSelector": "$.Payload.baz",
"ResultPath": "$.fred"
```

This puts the literal string "$.Payload.baz" into the output, not the dereferenced value.

It seems ResultSelector wants to build an object, so then I tried:

```
"ResultSelector": { "fred.$":"$.Payload.baz" },
"ResultPath": "$"
```

This *replaces* the entire step's input object, yielding just:

```
{ "fred":"ccc" }
```

And finally, the hybrid of those two:

```
"ResultSelector": { "fred.$":"$.Payload.baz" },
"ResultPath": "$.fred"
```

... yields:

```
{ "foo":"aaa" , "bar":"bbb", "fred":{"fred":"ccc"} }
```

Close (but no cigar)!

I'm a bit stumped for how to craft ResultSelector and ResultPath to achieve this simple overlay, and I feel like there's just some simple syntax trick that somehow I haven't found yet in the docs ... any ideas?

Comment: I'd be curious to see if someone can find a better solution, but the only thing I have managed in these cases is to have a `Pass` state afterward where I change the layout of the whole state.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but it seems inconceivable(!) to me that there's no way to do this ... **especially** given that the Lambda _function_ output will always be nested in the "Payload" key (and Lambdas are clearly advertised as **the** canonical step in Step Functions). ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'm following this question in the hopes that some SFN-Grandmaster is able to solve this, but I'm not too optimistic. If you check out the data flow simulator it seems like the expectation is to provide a JSON-Like structure for the ResultSelector...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To output the union of the task input and the task output, use `JsonMerge` in `ResultSelector`.  That  [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate) shallowly merges two objects.  Reference the task input from the [context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) and the output from the task payload.  `ResultSelector` always expects an object, so we need a temporary key.  I used `merged`, which I get rid of with `OutputPath`.

```json
"ResultSelector": {
    "merged.$": "States.JsonMerge($$.Execution.Input, $.Payload, false)",
},
"OutputPath": "$.merged",
```

Output:

```json
{
  "bar": "bbb",
  "baz": "ccc",
  "qux": "ddd",
  "foo": "aaa"
}
```

That's close, but not exactly what you wanted.  You want a *partial* union of the task input and output, dropping `qux` and renaming `baz`.  To do that, we do the `JsonMerge` thing, but with a subset of the task output constructed with the `Format` and `StringToJson` intrinsic functions:

```json
"ResultSelector": {
  "merged.$": "States.JsonMerge($$.Execution.Input, States.StringToJson(States.Format('\\{\"fred\":\"{}\"\\}', $.Payload.baz)), false)"
},
"OutputPath": "$.merged",
```

✅ Output:

```json
{
  "bar": "bbb",
  "foo": "aaa",
  "fred": "ccc",
}
```

Comment: My understanding was that `$$.Execution.Input` refers to the original Input of the stepfunction and _not_ the **task** input. If that's true this is still cool but solves a different problem, correct?

Comment: @Maurice OP says it's the "input to that step (and function)", which I read as: task input = step function input.